# How do we use REGEXP_SUBSTR when the string has \n in it?

Tags: oracle11g

I have a string with '\n' without quotes in it and would like to find out what the syntax would be for REGEXP_SUBSTR.

e.g.
My string is,

'a\nnbc' .

When I try to run the command,

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('a\nnbc',
                      '[^\n]+',
                      1,
                      LEVEL
                      )
          AS myelement
  FROM DUAL
```

CONNECT BY     LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT ('a\nnbc', '\n') + 1
           AND PRIOR SYS_GUID () IS NOT NULL

I get

### MYELEMENT

a
bc

But I expect the result to be

### MYELEMENT

a
nbc

Thank!

Comment: If the string literally has `\n`, then the newline is two characters, and you can't negate it in a class because it will treat each character individually.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT ('a\nnbc', '\n')+1
```

> it will eliminate all the '\n' from the string 
>   that means it will go ahead till all n's are matched

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('a\nnnbc',
                      '[^\]+',
                      1,level)
          AS myelement
  FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT ('a\nnbc', '\n',1) AND PRIOR SYS_GUID () IS NOT NULL;
```

This will give answer as

> a
>
> nnbc

Comment: This solution is not correct as it is giving the result as

a  
nnnbc

The need is to just eliminate "\n" and expect the result to be 

a
nbc